# wrap text within <li> using css

Tags: html, css

I have a ul containing a bunch of li's. In each li there is an image and caption. The li or image do not have a set width. I want to wrap the text so its only as wide as the image above it. It's something like this fiddle

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4hvaLjc/

I want the text under the image to wrap to the width of the image.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: You could use javascript to get the width of the image and set the .figcaption div to that width.  Also, if you need to break the long words, you could use this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: I was hoping for no javascript! I thought it could be achieved using CSS alone

Answer (score 1):

You could give a fixed width to your li and use ellipsis for the text

```
.figures span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wisd81/uybgLrhf/)

Comment: I can't give a fixed width to the li as the images could be any size.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the exact context of your layout, but you could use flexbox and give a max-width to the li. That way the img inside will adapt to the container. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wisd81/uybgLrhf/2/)